# AdaptiveCard doesn't render in Office 365 Proplus Outlook

Tags: outlook, adaptive-cards

I am unable to render AdaptiveCard in the Outlook software of Office365. It delivers as an attachment or shows the following message

This message was sent from the MessageCard Playground tool.

If the card doesn't appear, install Actionable Messages Debugger Outlook add-in to debug the issue.

JSON payload of the card attached to this message:

My question is how do I make it work or AdaptiveCard is not available for Office 365 outlook version?

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"originator": "<id>",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "columns": [
            {
                "width": 1,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "padding": {
                            "top": "None",
                            "bottom": "None",
                            "left": "Small",
                            "right": "None"
                        },
                        "items": []
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "backgroundImage": "https://filedepot.blob.core.windows.net/build/header.png",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "text": "TOM Notes",
                                "size": "Medium",
                                "color": "Light",
                                "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                                "wrap": true
                            }
                        ],
                        "padding": "None"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "padding": "Small",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                "columns": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Column",
                                        "width": "auto",
                                        "items": [],
                                        "padding": "None"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Column",
                                        "width": "stretch",
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                "text": "**Me** submitted on 23rd July"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                "text": "Hi ",
                                                "spacing": "",
                                                "size": "Small"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                "text": "**Reply**",
                                                "spacing": "",
                                                "size": "Small"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "Input.Text",
                                                "id": "comment",
                                                "isMultiline": true
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "padding": "None"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "padding": "None"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "ActionSet",
                                "id": "expenseActions",
                                "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                                "actions": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Action.Http",
                                        "headers": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "Content-Type",
                                                "value": "application/json"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "method": "post",
                                        "url": "Azure function",
                                        "title": "Submit",
                                        "body": "{<json payload>}"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "type": "Column",
                "padding": "None"
            }
        ],
        "padding": "None"
    }
],
"padding": "None"
```

}

[office license details](https://github.com/TechMinder/Shared/blob/master/office%20version.png)

Answer (score 0):

This was solved after working with Office 365 team. They have deployed the patch.